# how can I secure my flash exe file from decompiler

Tags: flash, security, exe, decompiler

how can I secure my flash exe file from decompiler?

i just need to protect my code..

If any software is available, which is the best one?

Answer (score 0):

In short no. In long, well [here's my answer the last time this came up](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/is-there-a-perfect-method-for-protecting-executable-files/3051#3051).

> No there is not. You can make it harder to reverse engineer, but
>   there's nothing you can realistically do to make it impossible, if
>   there's enough incentive to reverse engineer your application.
>   Professional malware researchers routinely reverse engineer much
>   tougher stuff then anything you'll find publicly.
>
> Theoretically, it may be possible using fully homomorphic encryption,
>   but the practical difficulties make it impossible and undesirable in
>   practice, even if it's theoretically possible.
>
> As for the best method of protection, I'd say just remove the
>   incentive to reverse engineer it in the first place. I'd be more
>   specific but it's not clear what kind of attacker you're trying to
>   protect against.